# Java 8 confusion - > String::compareToIgnoreCase

Tags: java, java-8

Can someone please help me in understanding below :

```
// This works fine
List list= Arrays.asList("a","b","A","B"); 
str.sort(String::compareToIgnoreCase);
```

Can I assign the above method reference to any variable ?

**??? holder = String::compareToIgnoreCase;**

however I can assign the object reference without any issues like :

```
String aa = "aa"; 
Function compareFunction = aa::compareToIgnoreCase;
```

Thanks in advance, Abdul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String::compareToIgnoreCase` is equal to anonymous class:

```
new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(String s, String str) {
        return s.compareToIgnoreCase(str);
    }
};
```

Therefore it can be assigned to variable with type `Comparator<String>` :

```
Comparator<String> compareToIgnoreCase = String::compareToIgnoreCase;
```

At the same time the expression `aa::compareToIgnoreCase;` means the function with string parameter `aa` that return Integer.

```
new Function<String, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(String str) {
        return aa.compareToIgnoreCase(str);
    }
};
```

Or:

```
Function<String, Integer> fun = aa::compareToIgnoreCase;
```

The difference between `String::compareToIgnoreCase;` and `aa::compareToIgnoreCase;` is that in the first case we need 2 parameters: string on which method `compareToIgnoreCase` will be invoked, and string that will passed in this method. It perfectly match the signature of [`int compare(T o1, T o2);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T-).

In the second case you alredy have one parameter (`aa`). So you need just one, that will be passed into `compareToIgnoreCase`. It exactly match [`R apply(T t);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#apply-T-)

Comment: Thanks , but how the below became function : String aa = "aa"; 
Function compareFunction = aa::compareToIgnoreCase; .. both refer to the same method .. for one its comparator and for other its function ?

Comment: @AbdulMohsin updated. *both refer to the same method..* right, but in the first case it is implementation of method `int compare(string,string)` and it the second case it's implementation `Integer apply(String)`

Comment: Thanks so much .. one last question .. how a programmer can guess that String::compareToIgnoreCase will resolve to a comparator .. as its signature is :     public int compareToIgnoreCase(String str) {
        return CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.compare(this, str);
    }

Comment: @AbdulMohsin Good question. In expression `String::compareToIgnoreCase` we don't have any specific object (unlike `aa::compareToIgnoreCase`). It means that specific object will be passed as a string parameter and at that string method `compareToIgnoreCase` will be invoked with another string parameter that will be passed also. It perfectly match the signature of `int compare(T o1, T o2);`

Comment: @AbdulMohsin So, the expression `aa::compareToIgnoreCase` already has one string (`aa`). It needs only one parameter, that exactly match `R apply(T t);`

Comment: Perfect ! .. Thanks so much for the help

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String args[]) {
  String str1 = "Strings are immutable";
  String str2 = "Strings are immutable";
  String str3 = "Integers are not immutable";

  int result = str1.compareToIgnoreCase( str2 );
  System.out.println(result);

  result = str2.compareToIgnoreCase( str3 );
  System.out.println(result);

  result = str3.compareToIgnoreCase( str1 );
  System.out.println(result);
```

}
}

Comment: Can you please explain your code and how this answers the question?